# ¿Como probar método de registro de inyección de dependencias?

Tags: c#, .net

He implementado inyección de dependencias en mi proyecto de tipo net7, he leído mucho sobre la diferencia de los métodos que se utilizan para registrar los servicios, como el addtransient, addscoped y el addsingleton, quiero saber si existe una forma de comprobar que este usando el método correcto o como me podría dar cuenta que es el incorrecto? dejando de lado la teoría

Comment: Lo correcto o incorrecto depende del caso puntual para el que los estes usando, por tanto tu pregunta, así como está planteada, es imposible de responder